# Controlling mouse scroll zoom in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, zoom

When I use the mouse scroll wheel to zoom in Inkscape, it is all too easy to rocket from useless big to useless small.  Is there a way to control the sensitivity of the mouse scroll wheel zoom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Behavior > Steps > Zoom in/out by

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the mouse wheel to zoom you can also use the number keys 1 to 5 for zoom presets. I found this more convenient than scrolling.

<kbd>1</kbd> zoom 1:1
<kbd>2</kbd> zoom 1:2
<kbd>3</kbd> zoom to selection
<kbd>4</kbd> zoom to drawing
<kbd>5</kbd> zoom to page

There are also keys for free zooming.

<kbd>+</kbd> zoom in
<kbd>-</kbd> zoom out

See [here](https://inkscape.org/doc/keys.html) for more keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  I knew about 4, +, and -, but not the others.